# Cannot set output dim of Conv2D in keras

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras, mnist

Now I am studying AutoEncoder with CNN. For study, I created a model for MNIST data. But I could not set output dim of `Conv2d` correctly. Please see below model image. Although I expect the first `Conv2d` output should be `(None, 16, 28, 28)`, the actual output is `(None, 1, 28, 16)`. Regarding to the document, my code does not look bad.
https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d

Could you find any wrongs of my code?

**My environment**

- Python 3.6.0
- keras 2.0.2 (backend is Tensorflow)

**Code**

```
from keras.layers import Input, Convolution2D, MaxPool2D, UpSampling2D, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
input_img = Input(shape=(1, 28, 28))
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPool2D((2,2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPool2D((2,2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPool2D((2,2), padding='same')(x)

x = Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3,3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2,2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3,3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder= Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

from keras.utils import plot_model
plot_model(autoencoder, to_file="architecture.png", show_shapes=True)
```

[image]

**Updated**

I added `autoencoder.summary()`. So my question is why does not the first output of CNN became `(None, 16, 28, 28)`? `(None, 1, 28, 16)` is not my expectation.

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_181 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 28, 16)         4048      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_82 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 14, 16)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_182 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 14, 8)          1160      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_83 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 7, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_183 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 7, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_84 (MaxPooling (None, 1, 4, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_184 (Conv2D)          (None, 1, 4, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_72 (UpSampling (None, 2, 8, 8)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_185 (Conv2D)          (None, 2, 8, 8)           584       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_73 (UpSampling (None, 4, 16, 8)          0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_186 (Conv2D)          (None, 4, 16, 16)         1168      

_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_74 (UpSampling (None, 8, 32, 16)         0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_187 (Conv2D)          (None, 8, 32, 1)          145       
=================================================================
Total params: 8,273.0
Trainable params: 8,273.0
Non-trainable params: 0.0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**Updated2**

My input_img is designed for Theano. So I have to change like below. Otherwise I changed `image_dim_ordering` in `~/.keras/keras.json`

```
# Theano style
input_img = Input(shape=(1, 28, 28))

# Tensorflow style
input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
```

Comment: try using autoencoder.summary(), this will print all output shape information for each layer in the terminal, and see if there is a different result (or add it to your question).

Comment: I added summary and clarify my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the very common problem problem with the image ordering. Theano puts the channels dimension in the second element of the shape array, like `(samples, channels, width, height)`, while TensorFlow puts the channels dimensions at the end, like `(samples, width, height, channels)`. You are using the Theano ordering but the backend is Tensorflow.

Just change the shapes to match the correct ordering and it should work. Alternatively you can change image_dim_ordering to "th" in your `~/.keras/keras.json` file.